# Stream webcam via Socket io example

Tags: socket.io, webrtc

I've been searching the web for a simple example, of how I can stream webcam over socket io. I already figured out how to connect 2 peers and they can send messages to eachother, but how can I send the webcam stream p2p as well?
I've tried several webrtc examples, but they don't really fit my needs.

I feel like it should be very simple, but can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Can anyone come up with a simple example?

I know how I can activate the camera and save the stream with:

```js
const localVideo = document.getElementById("local-video");
const remoteVideo = document.getElementById("remote-video");
let mediaStream;

function activateVideoStream() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: true,
            audio: true
        })
        .then(stream => {
            mediaStream = stream;
            if (localVideo) {
                localVideo.srcObject = stream;
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

But how can I emit the stream to another user via socket.io over Node?

User 2 should emit his stream back to user 1 as well.

Comment: Why do you want to use socket.io? Why not RTCPeerConnection?